# How to track multiple accounts using NEW analytics.js?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

I need to track pageview for two accounts on one page, using Google's new analytics.js. There is plenty of tutorials and examples how to do it with older ga.js. But all I have found was this [Analytics documentation page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers). I have written my code to suit the given example, but it only tracks views for first (default) tracker, but not for the second one.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3', 'domain.com');
  ga('create', 'UA-ZZZZZZZZ-1', {'name':'b'});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('b.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Anyone has any idea what is wrong with my code ? Looks good to me according to Google's example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code for multiple accounts tracking using analytics.js is correct, I have successfully tested a similar code in my site. So you need to check the following for any possible error:

1, Confirm if both tracking data are sent. For example in chrome, use GA debugger plugin for chrome and then in javascript console, see if you are getting the below details for both your tracking ids

```
adSenseId        (&a)   425734287 
apiVersion       (&v)   1 
clientId         (&cid) xx.xx
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8 
flashVersion     (&fl)  11.8
hitType          (&t)   pageview
javaEnabled      (&je)  1 
language         (&ul)  en-us 
location         (&dl)  domain.com 
referrer         (&dr)
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
screenResolution (&sr)  1366x768
title            (&dt)  yourdomaintitle 
trackingId       (&tid) UA-XXXXXXXX-3 
viewportSize     (&vp)  1364x361
```

Ideally you should see this as your code is correct and this means your website is correctly sending 2 tracking signals.

2, For your second tracking id, ensure the **tracking id** is exactly same as the one in your GA **web property**

3, Ensure you have not applied any **filters** to the corresponding **view** inside your web property which may filter out the traffic . Incase you are using some filters, take an unfiltered view and see if you are seeing hits in the realtime overview

Comment: It is strange, because everything looks fine. I have sucessfully installed GA debugger plugin, it returns exactly same log for first and second trackingID.
I have also checked that trackingID is correct and I am not using any filters.
It's really puzzle to me :-(

Comment: are you getting any hits in your realtime view for your 2nd property, when you access your website?

Comment: can you do a test by creating a new property and using the new tracking id to replace your 2nd one and then check if you are getting hits in the real time view for the new one?

Comment: OK, so creating new property did the trick and it works now as exptected. Thanks for effort.

Answer (score 27):

Working with Multiple Tracking Objects

To solve this, you must create a tracking object for each web property to which you want to send data:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-1', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'});  // New tracker.
```

Once run, two tracker objects will be created. The first tracker will be the default tracking object, and not have a name. The second tracker will have the name of newTracker.

To send a pageview using both trackers, you prepend the name of the tracker to the beginning of the command, followed by a dot. So for example:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for new tracker
```

Answer (score 9):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers

This has since been simplified, using a fourth argument - updated by Google on Dec 15, 2015.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the example in [Analytics documentation page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers), aren't you supposed to do:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-ZZZZZZZZ-1', 'auto', {'name':'b'});
// note this last argument            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: 4th argument surely?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old answer, but since I didn't see anyone mention this solution for pushing to both accounts at once, I thought I would share it...

Using multiple trackers is the way to go, but if you want to always push in both accounts, override `ga` function like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', {
    'name': 'myCustomTracker',
    'cookieDomain': 'auto'
});
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'auto');

ga(function () { //Wait for Analytics to be fully loaded
    var oldGa = ga;
    ga = function () { //Override ga function to call both trackers
        if (arguments && arguments.length > 0) {
            oldGa.apply(null, arguments);
            arguments[0] = "myCustomTracker." + arguments[0]; //Edit first argument to call second tracker.
            oldGa.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    };

    ga('send', 'pageview'); //Perform page view on both trackers at once.
});
```

Like this you'll be able to call `ga`functions like before, pushing data to both trackers at once!