# Is my code for correct for having two accounts for the same website?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website, and it already has the following tracking code:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Now I need to add tracking to another account. Is the following code right? (I just inserted a line for UA-yyyyyyyy-1 without changing anything else)

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-yyyyyyyy-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

### Update

Followed this link: [How to track multiple accounts using NEW analytics.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997966/how-to-track-multiple-accounts-using-new-analytics-js)

Created similar code as follows. It seems working. Any possible issue?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('create', 'UA-yyyyyyyyy-1', {'name':'b'});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('b.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, your code will track only for `UA-yyyyyyyy-1` property. Change the code like below:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','UA-yyyyyyyy-1']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

This will send the two pageview hits, one to `UA-yyyyyyyy-1` and other to `UA-xxxxxxxx-1`.

---

***Debug / Validate***

The code is very easy to validate. 
Steps for Chrome browser:

- Right click on any web page, inspect.
- Go to console tab, paste the above code and press enter.
- Go to network tab, and you will see two separate requests (__utm.gif) sent for `UA-yyyyyyyy-1` and `UA-xxxxxxxx-1`.

Comment: Tushar, if I want to add another account in the future, would it be okay for me to insert a new line in your code such as  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','UA-zzzzzz-1'])? Just asking.

Comment: yep, @curious1 it would be ok, but can u please tell me why u are using two properties? Also its just a suggestion, please upgrade to universal analytics, the one you are using is legacy and its deprecated, and will be discontinued in longer run

Comment: We have a legacy website. We also have a new website. The first account (legacy site) is there for a long time. Now we want to INCLUDE its web stats into the new website (so that we can know totals easily). Am I doing things right with the above code?. Please note that they are two accounts, not two properties. A general question: if I want to track a site's stats independently and also include its stats into another website, should I use two properties or two accounts?

Comment: oki first, the hierarchy in GA is account > property > view. So in the same account, you have multiple properties. Each property is identified by its UA id. So two different UA id means two different properties. Secondly, yes you
 can do that but rest depends on domains. new / old websites are on different domain ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145228/discussion-between-tushar-and-curious1).

Comment: The legacy site looks like`http://sub.example.com`. The new site looks like `http://www.example.com`

Comment: @curious1 oki then keep doing the same thing, I would suggest you one more thing, since page dimension will not tell you which domain the URL is from, please create a new view in your new website ga property. Add a filter that would make the page dimension to contain full URL along with hostname. So that you can easily create the reports. Please create new fiew and add the filter I have explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185657/track-goals-across-subdomains-in-google-analytics/44185949#44185949.

Comment: Tushar, thanks for the advice and all the info! Have a GREAT weekend! Best.

Comment: Hello Tushar, I implemented the code you suggest, but I am not able to see the results in Google Analytics for the second account. I followed this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997966/how-to-track-multiple-accounts-using-new-analytics-js and created similar code. It seems working. Would you please take a look at it and see whether there are any implications? Thanks!